# Restore input value to last valid string

Tags: javascript

Currently I am using **keydown** event on input field for validating 30 characters limit. When user enter 31th character then validation message comes "Please enter 30 character". But when I  select the whole text by simply double click on textbox and press any letter/number then text does not delete and it shows message "Please enter 30 character" . I want to delete whole text  when user press letter/number. Currently I am using :

```
$('#inputBox').live("keydown", function(event) {

    var inputLength = $(this).val().length;
    var boolPassValidation = false;

    if (event.keyCode === 8) {
        boolPassValidation = true;
    }


    if (inputLength >= 30 && !boolPassValidation) {
        alert("Please enter a valid PO number, 30 characters max.");

    }

    return false;
} else return true;
});
```

Any Suggestion would be great help.

Comment: Reason: This is because you're returning `false` in that handler making jQuery to stop the default behaviour of the keypress (inserting the key). Your validator gets executed but the char isn't inserted.

Answer (score 1):

***[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/t4uxs6ob/1/)***

Depends on the jQuery v. you use, but `.live()` method  is deprecated <sup>(since v.1.7 and removed from 1.9)</sup> - use `.on()` instead:

```
$(document).on("input", "#inputBox", function(e) {
    var v = this.value;
    if (v.length > 30 && e.which!==8) {
        alert("Please enter a valid PO number, 30 characters max.");
        this.value = this.dataset.oldVal;
    }else{
        this.dataset.oldVal = v;
    }
});
```

If you're searching for a string length of 30 characters, than you need to use `>30` instead of `>=30` otherwise you'll alert on 30 characters, which is fine.

Use jQuery's `event.which` instead of *keyCode* for better xBrowser compatibility

IF your `#inputBox` is not dynamically generated than you can simply use `$("#inputBox").on("input", function(e) {` otherwise try to use a static parent `#` selector instead of `$(document)`

<sub>P.S: you can additionally add `maxlength=30` property to your input element</sub>

Comment: C. Bulijan one problem occurs. After entering 30 character, when user put any character between string then it is accepted.I don't want to put any character in textbox. When user press delete button then it can accept the character and when limit reaches 30 then it again should show a message.Means input box accept only 30 character.